# I have deployed an API on elastic beanstalk and it is accessible within its VPC, how do I make it accessible publicly?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-vpc

I cannot find a clear answer in the documentation.  I selected the "Assign public IP" option when creating it but cannot find said public IP anywhere in the configurations.

I'm literally one step from hosting this service publicly and cannot get it to work.  Any pointers?

Comment: Any reason not to use the API Gateway to route to your API?

Comment: I don't know how that works, I'll check it out

Comment: Seems like overkill.  I have a fully built-out rest API already hosted, API gateway seems redundant.   I just want to be able to access the resource url from the outside world, like I was able to when my service was hosted without a vpc...

Answer (score 0):

Is there a gatweway available for the public IP to reach to the internet? simply attaching the public IP will not enable your instance to reach the internet. You need to ensure there is a routing available for the instance via Amazon VPC. Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-ip-addressing.html

Comment: I kind of just wanted to be able to hit the resource url from the outside world,  like I was able to when my service is hosted without a vpc.... I'll deal with ips and dns stuff later.   I can't host the service outside a vpc because my rds instance is inside one

Comment: @kamii i think when u are saying outside a vpc you really mean the `default vpc`. regardless you can have a public and a private talk to each other if u have the correct routing setup. refer [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.Scenarios.html) here. If you really want a very easy setup it's best launch everything in the default vpc and lock the SGs of the RDS to the web-layer

Comment: i previously had created a beanstalk application with no VPC designated, and the configuration's network section was completely blank.  That one I could access from anywhere via the resource URL.   It was great.  I'm in way over my head on networking stuff, I'm normally a data/backend guy and don't touch the admin/ops stuff at all.  Thanks for trying to help I'm still pretty confused why it's so hard to just set up a proxy that allows outside requests to hit a url and map to a service in my VPC heh